# Tooltip for show n more comments has aged

Tags: bug, comments

The Tooltip for `show n more comments` has incorrect text, a left-behind from the previous arrangement before the split to add/show for comments.

If you click on it to add a comment, as advised, you can't. Not a biggie.

[image: expand to show all comments on this post, or add one of your own]

The text for `add a comment` is not brilliant either.

[image: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.]

I know what it means, but it has several possible interpretations. Best laugh I've had all day.

Ah. It seems that the text on the `add a comment` Tooltip varies. Perhaps if someone can cast an eye over all the text which is used? The other two examples I've seen look fine (including the one in the description of the image link here, some fancy editing by a kind person).

Comment: "Best laugh I've had all day." - You must work in a cave!

Comment: @JonH Is that a suggestion, an order, a speculation that caves are not fun places to work in, a speculation that caves are really humorous places to work in, or none of the above? Same problem as the example text :-) "Use comments to ask... *sotto voce* Avoid answering questions [asked] in comments, [that'll wind 'em up, good'n'proper]". OK, probably just me.

Comment: I must be missing the humor in that tooltip.

Comment: @TylerH You will be asked questions in the comments. Avoid answering them. The "ask" implies question. The actual reference to the word "question" has a different context. Apply the same context, and it ruins the intended understanding. The Starship navigator strained his eyes through the viewscreen. If you notice the application of a different meaning, it ruins a ripping passage in an SF yarn (paraphrasing a point by Ursula Le Guin as advice to budding SF authors).

Comment: A downvote on a bug report? The humour never ends. Perhaps a developer has visited. I only found out today that there is a link for how to report as a bug. I should read it. Now I have to find it again...

Comment: I wonder what happened to the original responder's comment. But I just don't find that kind of stuff funny, I guess. By the way, @BillWoodger, downvotes in meta signify differences of opinion. A downvote on this question means someone disagrees that this is a bug.

Comment: Many apologies to Vonda N. McIntyre :-)

Comment: @TylerH, me too. Anyway, a tooltip which says click to add a comment, and then you still can't, just seems buggy to me. I guess the alleged humour has detracted from the main issue. In the past, I've done a lot of work on other people's writing, so I'm very aware of these types of things. A lot with non-English speakers, so I know that something which is otherwise "perfect" at a very high reading level, can still be completely misunderstood by a non-native-speaker.

Comment: When it says `show 3 more comments`, often that should be `show 0 more comments` (because there are no more). Why is that?

Comment: I have no clue. If you put together a screenshot and a link to a question which exhibits the behaviour, you can ask a question here about it. Make sure you look for similar questions, suggestions of questions which may have an answer will present themselves whilst you write the question.

Comment: @BillWoodger, it seems I misunderstood what `show 3 more comments` means. I thought it meant show the next 3 comments chronologically. Evidently it means to show 3 comments that have initially been omitted (as with Boris's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby)).  Those three may be the ones with the fewest votes.  I'd think that would render much of the commentary meaningless.  No?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it shows all the comments in their original time sequence. Personally I always click on it when it is there, otherwise you can't relying on a sequential presentation. If you're saying that makes the original higgledy-piggledy comment presentation fairly meaningless, I'd agree.

Comment: @BillWoodger, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

If I may read in between the lines, your suggestion is therefore

1. For the "Show *n* more comments" tooltip:

   > Expand to show all comments on this post.
2. For the "Add a comment" tooltip on questions:

   > Use comments to ask for clarification or to add more information.  Avoid using comments to answer the question.
3. For the "Add a comment" tooltip on answers, preserve the existing text:

   > Use comments to ask for clarification or to add more information.  Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

   Or is that too vague, as well?  What, after all, is a comment that is *like* "+1" but *isn't* "+1"?  Is "+100" *like* "+1"?  Is "thank you, that solved my problem pefectly" *like* "thanks"?  Perhaps we need to change it to

   > Use comments to ask for clarification or to add more information.  Avoid comments that merely express support (or disdain) without adding useful information.

Comment: Congrats on the recent 10K :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: A comment that expresses support, doesn't add information to the answer, and is also completely off-topic for the original question.  Oh, you are just asking for trouble, aren't you?   (P.S.  Thanks!)

Comment: I wasn't thinking of a feature request, but 1, yes (or perhaps `Expand to show all comments on this post in their original sequence`). 2, perhaps - the power of the definitive article. However, a lot of users don't have English as their first language, so maybe still too confusing? I don't have a problem with the content of other Tooltip text I've seen, but I've seen at least three different ones, so don't know how many others there may be, so whilst the fix goes in, I'm just suggesting a perusal of all that there may be. Thanks. +1. Me too.